# I'm using MathQuill with NextJS and the font resolution is horrible. Why's that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mathquill

Matrix brackets appear blurry.

[image]

- I'm using NextJS. I tried with Creat React App, and the resolution there is fine.
- I'm using TailwindCSS and globalsCSS.
- I'm using my own fork of `react-mathquill`, which includes support for matrices. [Link](https://github.com/adoallo/react-mathquill).

I'm not sure what else to share, but here's my tailwind.config.js file, in case it helps:

```
module.exports = {
content: ["./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"],
darkMode: "class",
theme: {
  extend: {
    colors: {
      "primary": "#0F52BA",
      "primary-hover" : "#1366e9", 
      "typography" : "#313131",
      "sidebar" : "#FAFAFA",
      "dropdown-hover" : "gray-500"
    },
    fontFamily: {
      "open" : ['"Open Sans"', "sans-serif"]
    }
  },
},
plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
}
```